# Making one's complement 1111 to signed magnitude 0000

Tags: verilog

```
always begin
if (a[3]&a[2]&a[1]&a[0] == 1) begin
b[3]=0;
end
end
```

I need this code because in one's complement, 1111 is -0, and I have to change this to 0000.  But, there's an error:

```
 Illegal reference to net "b".
```

I want to make `b[3]` to 0 when `if` statement is true.

I used `==` and other operators, but there's always an error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you declared `b` as a `wire`.  If so, you should declare it as a `reg` instead.

Also, your `always` block creates an infinite (zero-time) loop.  You probably meant to add a sensitivity list, such as `@*`:

```
reg [3:0] b;
always @* begin
    if (a[3]&a[2]&a[1]&a[0] == 1) begin
        b[3]=0;
    end
end
```

---

Unless you want a latch to be inferred, you should add an `else` clause and set `b[3]` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

- Declared ***wires***: Assign them in "assign" statements.
- Declared ***regs***: Assign them in "always" block statements.

Hint: If you want to check when all the bits of a variable are in "1", you can use an AND reduction as:

```
wire [3:0] b;
assign b[3] = ~(&a);
... assignments for the rest of "b"
```

Also, try to have a defined state for every condition, for example, there is a missing "else" in the always statement, this would generate a latch (not reliable).